# Application Menu in different place after elevating privileges

Tags: unity, 16.04, titlebar, menu-bar

I am on Ubuntu 16.04. I have set my application menus (file, edit, view, help etc.) to be in window's title bar and always visible. ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2dFp.jpg))

When I run applications like `bleachbit` or `gedit` or `virtualbox` in user mode, application menus show up correctly in window's title bar (as expected).

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when I open `bleachbit` or `gedit` or `virtualbox` with root privileges, application menus behaviour is not consistent.

1 : `bleachbit as root` shows application menus but it does not show them in title bar. It also shows window title `Bleachbit` in title bar which I don't want.

[image]

2 : `sudo gedit` completely removes the title bar. So no application menus.

[image]

3 : `sudo virtualbox` also displays application menus in wrong place. It also changes the scrollbar and font (looks more like windows 95 than ubuntu).

[image]

**So I want to know if it is possible to get the application menus back to the title bar when using in root mode. If yes, how?**

Note : I know the risk of running as gui programs root. Also the problem is not limited to these 3 programs specifically. Other programs such as `synaptic package manager`, `wireshark` have the same problem.